# How to make a controller manually/forcefully reload in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am developing an application in MEAN JS. I need the header controller to reload upon login to refresh some data. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading the header controller. Add some more details (ie. code)

Comment: How about instead of "reloading" a controller, you save you data to a Model when you login and the header pulls data from that model.

Comment: It's the Authentication that need refreshed. It's doesn't seem to refreshed.

Comment: It is very vague what you are saying. There are a lot of ways to do Authentication. Are you using a library, did you manually code it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ui-router for your states? If so you can just use:

```
$state.reload();
```

Unfortunately you haven't got much information on implementation to help further